# Angular 6 Dev / Test Configuration Settings

Tags: angular

In the angular.json file what configuration settings are recommended for dev or test environments?  Or in general what do the settings do?  I've checked angular.io and the github wiki but couldn't see any explanation.

My dev is just a copy of prod right now with just the environment.x.ts replacement.

```
        "dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        },
```

Comment: I would rather set aot to false in the dev mode 
since the aot, will need a full build of the app everytime you make a change.

Comment: @xelilof i heard that typescript can transpile/compile only the changed files - and AOT is or will be compatible with that, so AOT won't need to build everything in the future, only deltas, so we can use --aot with ng serve